# Mechanism for determining EWS and REST URL

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices

I have what I hope is a quick question. We are trying to track down why a specific EWS/REST API URL is being returned in OWA by Office Add-ins. Are you able to share the mechanism by which the REST and EWS URLs are determined when running Office.context.mailbox.ewsUrl (or .restUrl). How does the framework determine the right URL to use when in OWA. It doesn't appear to make any extra calls to Exchange. The specific JS in use is outlook-web-16.01.js. It looks like when the Extensions load a service.svc action called GetExtensibilityContext is used and this returns the EWS and REST URLs. However, we were hoping for some more information about what properties in Exchange would impact which URL is used here.

What we are seeing external URLs returned that are only set on four servers where other servers in the environment do not have an external URL set, including the servers where the mailbox in question resides.

Is it designed that if there's an external URL set anywhere in the environment, that is what is returned for the EWS/REST URLs?

Comment: Does Outlook itself use the same endpoint for doing its job?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an add-in is launched, it creates an instance of an office object inside the global window object.
Many of the common attributes are stored in that instance of the office itself.
Like ItemId of the item on which the add-in has been opened.

For instance, you can check all the office attributes in the console itself.
Switch the **Javascript context** to the iframe (since add-ins are loaded inside an iFrame).
Then console log the **window.office.context.mailbox** object. You'll find all the attributes stored with respect to the item there.

Hope it answers your query.